# Form submit with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm having issues running my code can any one verifiy it and tell me why it's not working properly?. My javascript doesn't seems to be working fine and the best that I got was the first vars to display. I'm really new to javascript thought.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> Template Suivi Client </title>
 <link rel="icon" href="icone.ico" type="image/x-icon">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="aidememoire.css">
 <script>
  function myFunction {
    alert();
    var compte = form.inputcompte.value;
    var nom = form.inputnom.value;
    var telephone = form.inputtelephone.value;
    var quand = form.inputdate.value;
    var hdebut = form.inputheuredebut.value;
    var hfin = form.inputheurefin.value;
    var info = form.inputdescription.value;
    document.getElementById("displaycompte").innerHTML = ("Numéro de Compte     Client: " + compte);
    document.getElementById("displaynom").innerHTML = ("Nom du Client : " + nom);
    document.getElementbyId("displaytelephone").innerHTML = ("Numéro de téléphone : ");
    document.getElementbyId("displayquand").innerHTML =("Date :"  + quand);
    document.getElementbyId("displayheured").innerHTML = ("Heure de début : " + hdebut);
    document.getElementById("displayheuref").innerHTML = ("Heure de fin: " +hfin);
    document.getElementById("displaydescription").innerHTML =("Déscription :" + info);
   }
 </script>
 </head>


 <body>

<h2 style="text-align: Center">
Template Suivi Client
</h2>

<form method="get">

Numéro de Compte Client : 
 <input type="text" name="inputcompte">

 <br><br>

 Nom du Client :  
  <input type="text" name="inputnom">

<br><br>

  Numéro de téléphone :  
  <input type="text" name="inputtelephone">

 <br><br> 

 Date :  
 <input type="date" name="inputdate">

 <br><br>

 Heure de début :  
 <input type="time" name="inputheuredebut">

<br><br>

 Heure de fin :  
 <input type="time" name="inputheurefin">

<br><br>

Description du problème :  
<input type="text" name="inputdescription">

<br><br>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(from.here)"> Soummettre </button>

</form>

<br><br><br>


<p id="displayfinal"> Produit final s'affichera ici </p>
<p id="displaycompte">
</p>
<p id="displaynom">
</p>
<p id="displaytelephone">
</p>
<p id="displayquand">
</p>
<p id="displayheured">
</p>
<p id="displayheuref">
</p>
<p id="displaydescription">
</p>




</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: *My javascript doesn't seems to be working fine* What is the problem?

Comment: Check for error messages in the console. For starters `function myFunction {` should be `function myFunction() {`.

Comment: You need to learn to use breakpoints and standard debugging features.

Comment: @zero298 first time trying javascript

Comment: @Guffa the console helped out a bit. at least i'm able to tell whats not working

Comment: You have missed ().It should be myFunction().

Comment: Here from is not defined .

Answer (score 1):

You are using a variable `form` that is not defined anywhere.

You can sent the reference to the form from the button:

```
onclick="myFunction(this.form)"
```

Catch the parameter in the function:

```
function myFunction(form) {
```

Answer (score 0):

try giving the form an id, like `<form id="abc" method="GET">...</form>`
then use `$("#abc").off('submit');` (after the end of the form)

Comment: This can be done without `jQuery` very easily and the question doesn't even tag it.

Answer (score 0):

The info that I got from the console [ Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inputcompte' of undefined ] . It happens to all my variables